# Beginner using MYSQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql

Good day everyone and thank you in advance.

I'm studying database design and we started with SQL basics, specifically relational operators. Next, we will be doing proper-ish, basic python + SQL.

In order to learn the work, I figured the best would be to use a SQL program to help me visualize the relational operators' effects on a database. First I used SQL Fiddle, which seemed okay, but the next morning all my work was gone, and it seems they are having technical problems. So I switched to MYSQL Workbench, easily created all the tables, but now I can't seem to run a simple script. More specifically, I do not know how to. The only examples available on the web are outdated, and or I lack the knowledge to properly search for the answers.

I know it's a dumb, low-level question, but I would really appreciate it if I can just figure this out and run basic scripts on the database.

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sh3Qf.png

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: There's a multitude of training materials and introduction videos to MySQL + SQL in general.